# Deriving Maxwell-Boltzmann momentum distribution

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I am studying statistical mechanics and I saw the following statement in my notes:

$$\frac{d\rho}{\rho} = \frac{e^{-\beta p^2/2m}}{(2\pi m k_B T)^{3/2}} 4\pi p^2 dp \quad \ldots (1)$$

where $\rho = \langle N \rangle /V$, the particle density and $p$ is momentum, $\beta = 1/k_B T$ where $T$ is the temperature, $k_B$ is Boltzmann's constant, $m$ is mass of the particle. We can see that the above equation denotes the momentum distribution function for an ideal gas.

I want to derive this equation from the Fermi distribution for particle density:

$$\rho = \frac{g}{h^3} \int \frac{1}{e^{\beta(p^2/2m - \mu)}+1} d\mathbf{p} \quad \ldots (2)$$
in the limit as $e^{\beta(p^2/2m - \mu)} \gg 1$, where $g=2$ for a Fermi gas.

My question is, how do I get equation $(1)$ from the above relation?

My attempt: Since we know that $e^{\beta(p^2/2m - \mu)} \gg 1$, equation $(2)$ becomes,

$$\rho = \frac{2}{h^3} \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\beta(p^2/2m - \mu)} dp_xdp_ydp_z \\ 
=\frac{2e^{\beta \mu}}{h^3} \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\beta(p^2/2m)} dp_xdp_ydp_z \\
=\frac{e^{\beta \mu}}{\sqrt{2}h^3} \cdot (2\pi m k_B T)^{3/2} $$

However, I don't see a way to make it to equation $(1)$.

I would appreciate any advice you have for me.

Comment: The integrations should have $-\infty$ as lower bound but then you seemed to have used the formula for the Gauss integral with lower bound at $-\infty$. So those two mistakes canceled. But why did the two in the numerator becomes a $\sqrt{2}$ in the denominator? Do I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's rewrite this in polar coordinates
\begin{equation} 
\rho = \frac{2}{h^3} \int dp \; 4\pi p^2 e^{-\beta (\frac{p^2}{2m} - \mu)}.
\end{equation}
Thus we see that the particle densitiy in the intervall $[p, p+dp]$ is
\begin{equation} 
d\rho = \frac{8\pi}{h^3} p^2 e^{-\beta(p^2/2m - \mu)} dp.
\end{equation}
Next we calculate $\rho$. This you have already done (But I think you have made a small mistake) $\rho = e^{\beta \mu} \frac{2}{h^3} (2\pi m k_B T )^{3/2}$. Deviding $d\rho$ by $\rho$ yields the desired result.